# How to retrieve a file recursively

Tags: java, recursion

I have a `Java` file that gets a file based on todays date.

e.g `20151202data.csv`

if todays file isn't available, it gets yesterdays. The program gets todays file fine, it's when I try to rollback is when I get errors. The response is empty.

**Code**

```
errorCount = 0;
public static JSONArray getJSON(String url)
  HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
  JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray();
  Object[] q = null;
  Deque<String> queue = new ArrayDeque<String>();
       try{  
            logger.info("\nSending 'GET' request to URL : " + url);
            HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);
            HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
            int responseCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
            logger.info("Response Code : " + responseCode);
            if (responseCode != 404){
             ...Do Things... 
            else{
             if(errorCount > 0){
               logger.info("Cannot find data.csv for " + getDayBefore(errorCount));
               return null;
             }else{
               errorCount++;
               logger.info("404: Today's file couldn't be found. Using " + getDayBefore(errorCount) + "data.csv");
               getJSON("/data/"+ getDayBefore(errorCount)+"data.csv");
               errorCount = 0;
              }
            }
            return jArray;
        }finally{
            httpClient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
        }
```

When I try to get yesterdays data I get `[]` as a response, even though `20151201data.csv` is an exact copy of `20151202data.csv` and a 200 response code is logged.

**Log**

```
Sending 'GET' request to URL : http://www.test.com/data/20151202data.csv
Response Code : 404
404: Today's file couldn't be found. Using 20151201data.csv
Sending 'GET' request to URL : http://www.test.com/data/20151201data.csv
Response Code : 200
```

**Response**

`[]`

Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: @guillaumegirod-vitouchkina that's exactly what this is doing in a failed case

Comment: problem seems to be in retrieving data (because 200 response code is OK). Where is your code to retrieve URL ?

Comment: what is dataLocation ?

Comment: @guillaumegirod-vitouchkina datalocation was renamed to `url` to clear confusion

Comment: could you, please, show a code working: this lacks {, jArray is empty, queue  is unused , ...  where do decode datas ? it's confusing.

Comment: Simplify your code to try and retrieve 20151201data.csv (hard-code it to do that) and show where you are outputting/checking the response. It will be much clearer what's going on

Answer (score -1, accepted):

first of all i would not use recursion, especially on a static method, for this problem; second it's not clear what happens before you get the response code AND the data back.

Also, you are downloading a csv from a method called `getJson`. That's confusing.

Where does the conversion from csv to json happen? That is not shown. 
Http response code is 200, ok, but is the response empty? Did you check if the csv is coming empty or with just the headers? Does the conversion from csv to json fail at any point? Maybe falling back to an empty list?

after question update:

you never return the result of the recursive `getJson` call

```
else {
           errorCount++;
           logger.info("404: Today's file couldn't be found. Using " + getDayBefore(errorCount) + "data.csv");
           /* return */ getJSON("/data/"+ getDayBefore(errorCount)+"data.csv");
           errorCount = 0;
          }
```

I would convert the recursion to a loop, so it's easier to read. I don't think recursion is the right tool for the job in this case.

Comment: you're just repeating my question back to me. Everything you've mentioned is in the question. My conversion works fine for todays file, why wouldn't it work fine with a file whose only difference is the file name? There is something I'm missing in the recursive call and it's returning empty...Also I'm retrieving JSON from a file, not downloading anything

Comment: it's incomprehensible: you use  HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url); - it is downloading. where do you use dataLocation?

Comment: you never return the result of the recursive `getJson` call. see update above

Comment: @user2560528 tthhheerrreeee we go